# Quickest way to add CSS and JavaScript to Sitecore

Tags: sitecore

I have a single page within Sitecore, containing a HTML table. I've added some CSS and JavaScript to the page, through the Sitecore HTML editor to allow DataTables.NET to format the table.

This work well, except that when a regular user goes to update the table using the rich text editor, my CSS and JavaScript is removed.

I can add the CSS to a generic CSS files, but the JavaScript contains initialization logic, so needs to be on the page itself.

What's the easy way to add references to CSS and JavaScript files?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a setting in web.config that is true by default.

```
<setting name="HtmlEditor.RemoveScripts" value="true"/>
```

Setting this to `false` will prevent the Rich Text Editor from stripping out the script blocks. But be aware that it will affect every single Rich Text field in your site, and it was put in there as a safety precaution. You can take a look at [this blog post](http://firebreaksice.com/prevent-sitecore-content-editor-from-stripping-script-tags/) for more info.

There are other code solutions, like adding a Multiline text field for your scripts which would not strip anything out but would require modifying the layout files but if you are comfortable editing the CSS file then I suggest you just do the same with your javascript file, add a unique ID/selector to your table (in the RTE) and then just initialize there. e.g.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#myCustomDatatable').dataTable( {
        "paging":   false,
        "ordering": false,
        "info":     false
    } );
} );
```

As long as the selector targets the table uniquely and the js files are loaded on your page this will run and format your table.

Answer (score 1):

If you have access to the file system, you can just add the js or css references to the appropriate layout file. Although I gather from your comments you weren't involved on the development of the site. I Expect that the people who did develop it purposely didn't provide a simpler way for you to do it for good reasons. So I would recommend contacting them.